# How to modify the following cypher syntax in AgensGraph?

Tags: cypher

MATCH (wu:wiki_user)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:wiki_doc{author:wu.uid}), (o:wiki_doc{editor:wu.uid})
RETURN wu.uid AS User_id, wu.org AS Organization, wu.email AS email, wu.token AS balance,
count(n) AS Writing, count(o) AS Modifying;

```
  user_id | organization |      email      | balance | writing | modifying
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "ailee" | "Org2"       | "hazel@gbc.com" | 5       |       0 |         0
  "hazel" | "Org1"       | "hazel@gbc.com" | 5       |       2 |         2


 match (n:wiki_doc{editor:'hazel'}) return n;
```

### n

```
  wiki_doc[9.11]
{"bid": "hazel_doc1", "cid": "Basic", "org": "Org1", "title": "Hello world!", 
"author": "hazel", "editor": "hazel", "revnum": 1, "created": "2018-09-25 
09:00:000", "hasfile": 2, "contents": "I was wrong", "modified": "2018-09-25 
10:00:000"}
```

(1 row)

In fact, the number of updates in the case of hazel is 1, and 2
queries are used when the above query is used.

How to modify the query so that only one can be normally viewed.

Answer (score 1):

> MATCH( `wu:wiki_user` )
>   OPTIONAL MATCH `(n:wiki_doc{author:wu.uid})`, `(o:wiki_doc{editor:wu.uid})`
>   RETURN wu.uid AS User_id, wu.org AS Organization, wu.email AS email, wu.token AS balance,
>   `count(distinct id(n)) as Writing, count(distinct id(o))` as Modifying;

```
  user_id | organization |        email        | balance | writing | modifying

 +----------------------------------------------------------+

 "ailee" | "Org2"       | "hazel@gbc.com"     | 5       |       0 |         0

 "hazel" | "Org1"       | "hazel@gbc.com"     | 5       |       2 |         1
```

(2 rows)